# .Net Core Session Cookie Not set when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, session-cookies, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net core 3.1 application that is using session cookies to keep track of some data. This is working perfectly fine on my dev machine, but the cookie is not set when deployed to an azure web app. What do I need to do differently to get this to work correctly in Azure?

I have the following in startup.cs

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSession();
    ...
}
```

I am setting the cookie with code similar to this:

```
session.SetString(_key, value);
```

I figure that there is a simple change that needs to be made in the configuration, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure web app will use ARR by default, you should make sure you have enabled the ARR affinity.

If ARR Affinity is enabled, the IIS server acting as the load balancer will place a cookie on responses that causes a user to always hit the same instance within their session. This is good for legacy application compatibility as they may not have been designed with load balancing in mind.

You could open your Azure web app service and find configuration --> general settings --> ARR affinity to on.

[image]